# Is there a way to hide the notes pane in powerpoint 2007's normal view?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I want this away altogether - not dragged as wee as it can be, but gone.

[image]

Comment: When you drag it down completely it's barely visible (just a few pixels, at least in PPT 2010). Why do you want it gone?

Comment: You're correct, it is barely present on screen when collapsed. I like to keep my interface as minimal as possible for a given task. It seems like something a user should have control over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Options (from the File Menu) and choose "Advanced" on the left. In the "Display" section there is a configuration option called "Open all documents using this view". Change that to "Normal - outline and slide".

Note: After choosing OK, you may need to close your powerpoint document and then reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that removes it entirely from the interface, including the separator. If I understand correctly the solution you've provided _does_ have it collapsed by default, and that is definitely and improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normal view, by definition, includes the notes pane.  As you've seen you can minimize it but not remove it altogether.  It's simply part of the view.

If you want just the slide (no thumbnails, outline or notes) you can still get at the old Slide view via a bit of VBA.

Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor
Press Ctrl + G to open the immediate window if it's not already visible
Paste this into the immediate window:

Activewindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

Press return.  Voila.  Slide view.

Or, probably more useful, hold down Shift while you click the little Normal view icon in the status/task/whatever bar at the bottom of the screen.  This should give you thumbnails or outline plus slide but no notes.

Comment: Wait ... my bad.  Shift + Click Normal view gives you Master view, not Slide view.  [bangs head on desk].  Now it's REALLY time to hang it up and go to sleep.